# how to get title of clicked component and use that title in another component?

Tags: reactjs

This compontent contains audio file title

```
function RecommandedAudios() {
    return (
        <div className="recommandedaudios">
            <h2>Recommanded</h2>
            <div className="recommandedaudios_audios">
                <AudioCard title="Arrows to Athens - Alive" />
                <AudioCard title="Arrows to Athens - Dust & Gold" />
                <AudioCard title="Arrows to Athens - Stars" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RecommandedAudios;
```

this is bottom component

```
function BottomAudioCard({title}) {
    return (
        <div className="songContainer">
            <div className="songDetails">
               <h4>{title}</h4>
               <p>Artist Name</p>
            </div>

            <div className="play"> 
            </div>

            <div className="time">
                Time
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BottomAudioCard;
```

and in this component i am  passing values

```
function AudioCard({ title, id }) {

    const [play, setPlay] = useState(false);
    const [playClass, setPlayClass] = useState("play");

    const audioEl = useRef(null);
    const playpause = useRef(null);
    
    const playSong = () =>{
        const listaudio = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
                listaudio.forEach((audio) => {
                if(audio === audioEl.current){
                    setPlay(true);
                    audioEl.current.play();
                    }
                else{
                    audio.pause();
                    audio.currentTime = 0;      
                    setPlayClass("pause");      
                }
            })
      }
      const pauseSong = () =>{
        setPlay(false);
        setPlayClass("play");
        audioEl.current.pause();
      }
    return (
        <div className="audiocard">
            <div ref={playpause} onClick={play ? pauseSong : playSong} className={`${playClass}`}></div>
            <div className="audiocard_info">
                <div className="audiocard_title">
                    <h5>{title}</h5>
                    <Link to={`/song/${id}`}>
                        <audio ref={audioEl} src={require(`../sounds/${title}.mp3`)}></audio>
                    </Link>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

so after clicking on any audio card i want that card title to be displayed in bottomaudiocontainer i how could i do that ??
on click i am not geeting title also is their any alternative for $(this).find() in reactjs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function static RecommandedAudios() {
    return (
        <div classNameEXT="recommandedaudios">
            <h2>Recommanded</h2>
            <div className="recommandedaudios_audios">
                <AudioCard tittle="Arrows to Athens - Alive" />
                <AudioCard tittlous="Arrows to Athens - Dust & Gold" />
                <AudioCard tit="Arrows to Athens - Stars" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RecommandedAudios;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use array for titles: `const titles = ["Arrows to Athens - Alive", "Arrows to Athens - Dust & Gold", "Arrows to Athens - Stars"]`

Second, create `onClick` function which will be passed as prop to `AudioCard`:

```
const onClick = (title) => () => {
  // dispatch it to store if you use Redux or save it using own solution
}
```

Third, map `AudioCard`s from `titles` array and pass title to `onClick` function:

```
function RecommandedAudios() {
    return (
        <div className="recommandedaudios">
            <h2>Recommanded</h2>
            <div className="recommandedaudios_audios">
                {titles.map(title => <AudioCard title={title} onClick={onClick(title)}/>}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RecommandedAudios;
```

Fourth, now you saved `title` and you can pass it to `BottomAudioCard`

Comment: if i am using {titles.map((title, i) => <AudioCard key={i} title={title} onClick={() => onClick(title)}/>)} then onclick event is not getting executed and if i am using {titles.map((title, i) => <AudioCard key={i} title={title} onClick={onClick(title)}/>)} then it is getting automatically executed without click event

Comment: It will be executed because when you pass `onClick(title)` it returns new function `() => { ... }` and this functions will be be passed to `onClick` event